# Can I ask about amateur airships, here on this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As the question said, let's say, I wanted to design a four-seater airship, and I have some structural flaw in my design. Can I ask questions about amateur lighter-than-air aircraft, or is this website only restricted to flaws with heavier-than-air aircraft.

Basically, are questions about lighter-than-air aircraft like aerostats, amateur blimps, amateur-airships etc. on-topic, or are they off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

On Drones and Model Aircraft SE, our main stipulation is that the questions be about *unmanned* vehicles. Lighter-than-air vehicles are entirely within the topic of our site, so feel free to ask away.

In your question, the airship sounds like a manned vehicle, which requires many more considerations than a basic unmanned vehicle. While we don't answer questions that are directly about manned vehicles like this, we could answer questions about the structure of a lightweight airship that isn't necessarily manned.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks.